# Run a function everyday in background in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I am stuck at this and would appreciate if someone can help me in this
I am a beginner and creating a iOS app **(want to support ios 5-7)**
My App will check for upcoming movies and show a notification if a movie has released that day, all movie data and date checks will be done by a function and movie release dates are stored in a local file
What I want to do is run my function every day (each 24 hours) in/from background even if app is not running, since I donot want the user to launch app every day to check for movie updates or releases, I want to check for this in BG

So, I have a function which will check and show a notification if today a movie released and want this function to be executed every day automatically even if my app isnt running/launched by the User

Comment: try to use push notification from your server side

Comment: Chancy was faster. Push notification are best solution. In iOS applications can't activate them selves for security reasons. Push notification will change state of your application icon and your app have to fetch updates when user will start application.

Comment: @MarekR R are push notifications you mentioned same as UILocalNotification ? Any example you have or if you can hint me a bit. What I want is user not to run the app to make that function execute to check if a movie has released (doesnt need net anyway)

Comment: UILocalNotification is not the same. You use that if you wish to schedule 'local' notifications which you know the exact time/date of. Hence the name local, doesn't require net. In your case it sounds as if you need to write an app that queries a service and pushes to your app.

Comment: @hajder in other words it will be impossible to do without push-notif aka can only be done when a user is connected to net (even though all data etc is avail locally)

Comment: I think you don't get it. With push notification your service server will perform some logic to check updates. When server detects that there is something new for the user, it sends to Apple push notification and then Apple sends this to device. Device will change state of your application icon and/or add some notification. With local notification the notification will be shown always at same time even if there is nothing new for user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Push Notification is the right solution. You can refer to [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/) .

Comment: But doesnt it require net connection if pushing notif from server side ? For that aspect I even had parse.com in mind but my need is without net as a user might not be using net the day movie releases, thats why I am storing movie dates in a local file and comparing current date with the date in the file to see if there is a release today. So if a user isnt connected to net, push notif wont work many a times

Comment: @user2897064 if you consider this,then what you can do is when user starts your app manually, you check whether its 24 hours and do you thing. if the user didn't start your app in every 24 hours, you cannot check. and there is no such service in background for you like android.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I am storing all the info in a local file, when the app is launched by user, it auto checks if the local file needs update  from my server (API), I wanted to keep this notification of movie release without user need to be online.  Chancy, yeah ofc app checks about release when its launched since it has a bookmarks tab as well, but a offline notification feature was something I really hoped for since in asia people dont always stay connected to net. Btw, if I really have to use push, should I use APNS or Parse ?

Comment: @user2897064 you can refer to the tutorial in my answer.

Comment: @Chancy yeah got my answer, seems I will have to include a note that push notifi. will need needs net conn. while documenting the app, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

For the complete solution, at server end, you need to maintain data per user/device over how much information has been sent to the user/device when the last time device was connected to internet.

And, based on the data available to the user/device, you can use combination of `UILocalNotification` and APNS (server driven). If the release dates are known (stored locally) then use `UILocalNotification` and otherwise use APNS (when info is not available locally or there is change of dates suddenly).